# Xamarin MVVM: updating control styling (font size, border color etc.) by some calculation results done in ViewModel

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm making first steps in learning Xamarin Forms and run into design question which can't find easy solution for. I want to utilize MVVM approach and implement it with best practices in mind, though I realize same thing could be done in different ways.

So I have Button and Label controls in View. Clicking button sends Command to ViewModel that runs some calculations (or delegates them to the model) and impacts text and visual representation of the Label in the text field. ViewModel has `Text` property to display in the textbox which could easily to be done with property bindings

```
<Label Text="Binding Text" ...></Label>
```

so once ViewModel modifies the text it's shown on a View updated, it's not a problem. The design in question is second part: I'm not sure how to update visual styling for the label, like border color and strikethrough style of font right after calculation is done in ViewModel, it's something that I believe only codebehind (xaml.cs) could properly do, not binding.

One of the approach would be to leave it as a command `xaml -> VM -> M`

```
<Button ButtonClickedCommand="{Binding RunCalculationsCommand}" ...>
```

and have VM to raise a certain ad-hoc event in ViewModel that codebehind catches and does it "styling" job: `VM -> xaml.cs`

Another is to have a regular event (not Command) raised on view that starts calculation in ViewModel and runs styling `xaml -> xaml.cs -> VM -> M`

```
<Button Clicked="RunCalculations_OnClicked" ...>
```

But then it's more tightly coupled and does not fully follows MVVM per my understanding.

Or I guess the best one could be something else that I'm not yet aware of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options: bind a [trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/triggers), or bind the control properties directly to VM.
Then, update VM properties in your button command.

1. Bind a trigger with preset styles.

```
<Label Text="{Binding Text}" TextColor="Green">
    <Label.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger
            Binding="{Binding CalculationResultIsNegative}"
            TargetType="Label"
            Value="true">

            <!-- set Specific Property -->
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Red" />

            <!-- or set Specific Style in App.xaml -->
            <Setter Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource RedStyleDefinedInAppXaml}" />

        </DataTrigger>
    </Label.Triggers>
</Label>
```

Update in your VM

```
void RunCalculationsCommandMethod ()
{
    //if...
    CalculationResultIsNegative = true;
    //else..
    //CalculationResultIsNegative = false;
}
```

2. Bind control properties in XAML

```
<Label Text="{Binding Text}"
       TextColor="{Binding ColorPropertyFromVM"}
       FontAttributes="{Binding FontAttributesProperty"} />
```

Update in your VM

```
void RunCalculationsCommandMethod ()
{
    //if...
    ColorPropertyFromVM = Color.Red;
    FontAttributesProperty = FontAttributes.Bold;
}
```

Comment: regarding 2: while I understand ViewModel is supposed to help View with some level of visualization, is it really a good practice in Xamarin to manage things like font styles and colors in VM?

Comment: I assume that option2 didn't follow MVVM strictly, I mean the view model is not supposed to touch the visual area. Also I use option1 most of the time, as all the visual stuff keeps either in the xaml file itself or the global style file, easy to be maintained by others.